# Angular metrial tabs not opening the first tab for outlets

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular-material2, angular-routing

I have the routes defined as shown below. When the user loads the application  with the URL --> http://localhost:4200/will-kit
I am getting only the TABS and don't see the first tab getting loaded by default

[image]

On click of start tab then the tab opens up and the url will be --> http://localhost:4200/will-kit/(taboutlet:./start)

[image]

```
const routes: Routes = [   { path: 'will-kit', component: WillKitLayoutComponent, children: [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: './start',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: './start',
        component: StartComponent,
        outlet: 'taboutlet'
    },
    {
        path: './you',
        component: YouComponent,
        outlet: 'taboutlet'
    },
    {
        path: './status',
        component: StatusComponent,
        outlet: 'taboutlet'
    } ]} ];
```

Tabs code in HTML

```
 <nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
            <a mat-tab-link class="mat-test" *ngFor="let routeLink of routeLinks; let i = index;" [routerLink]="[{outlets: {taboutlet: routeLink.link}}]"
              routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" 
(click)="activeLinkIndex = i" [active]="rla.isActive" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
      <label class="mat-subheading-1">{{routeLink.label}} </label>
            </a>

          </nav>
```

Comment: How your URL looks like when you open http://localhost:4200/will-kit  ? Btw if this is not some copy paste issue then  http://localhost:4200/will-kit/(taboutlet:./start) as url looks really strange for angular routes :)

Comment: It might be that you are missing `outlet: 'taboutlet'` in your redirect route or that you are using `./` in your routes which is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `AfterViewInit` function to open first tab by default

Answer (score 1):

Handled the route in AfterViewInit as suggested, This is loading the first tab by default

```
 public ngAfterViewInit() {

        this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { 'taboutlet': './start' } }], {
            relativeTo: this.route
        });
    }
```